# C++ function call within same namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

What is the correct way to call one function from another from the same namespace when using the 'using namespace' keyword in the implementation? I get following error:

> Call to 'bar' is ambiguous

when compiling this:

```
// Foo.h
namespace Foo
{
    void bar();
    void callBar();
}

// Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.h"
using namespace Foo;

void bar() {/* do something */}
void callBar() {bar();}
```

Comment: Looks good, must be something else wrong ...

Comment: this is exactly why you shouldn't do this!

Answer (score 7):

It appears that you are providing definitions of `bar` and `callBar` in the cpp file. In this case you should put the functions in the namespace `Foo` where they are declared, rather than importing that namespace with `using`:

```
#include "Foo.h"

namespace Foo {

    void bar() {/* do something */}
    void callBar() {bar();}

}
```

The `using namespace` directive tells the compiler that you want to call functions and refer to classes from the namespace `Foo` without qualifying their names explicitly; you can have multiple such directives in your file. It does *not* tell the compiler that the definitions that you provide below should belong to the namespace `Foo`, so the compiler dumps them in the top-level namespace.

The end result is that the compiler sees two `bar`s - the `Foo::bar()` declared in the `Foo` namespace, with external definition, and `::bar()` defined in your cpp file in the default namespace.

Comment: Aha, that makes perfect sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You have two `bar`s here. one **declared in namespace `Foo` but not defined** and another **declared and defined in the global namespace**. Both are reachable from the call site because you are using `using namespace Foo;`, hence the ambiguity for the compiler.

If the definitions of the functions are for the ones in the `Foo` namespace then you should put them in there too.

```
namespace Foo {
     void bar() {/* do something */}
     void callBar() {bar();}
}
```